# I want to disable the button by checking allover Database condition

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I am checking the time for which the doctor is appointed and if the doctor is appointed then we have to disable the Button for that specific time for 3 months. My condition is not satisfying the code and Foreach is not working properly

I have tried using eloquent but the code is not matching the condition

Controller

```
public function doctor(){
    $data['page_title'] = 'Doctor';
    $doctors = Doctor::all();
    $data['doctors'] = WebDoctorDetails::all();
    return view('frontend.doctor',['doctors'=>$doctors])- 
    >withData((object)$data);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div>
    <div class="main_div">
    <div class="buttons">
    @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    @if($doctor->transaction_id != NULL && $doctor->plan == "90" && $doctor->cabin == "Cabin 1" && $doctor->day =="Friday" && $doctor->time == "8.00 - 10.00")
    <script>
    $('#a').attr("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function() { enableSubmit('#a') }, 7776000);  
    </script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" id="a" data-target="#myModal">8.00 - 10.00</button>&nbsp;
    @else
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">8.00 - 10.00</button>&nbsp;
    @endif
    @endforeach
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">10.30 - 12.30</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">1.00 - 3.00</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">3.30 - 5.30</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4">6.00 - 8.00</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">8.30 - 10.30</button>&nbsp;
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my output like this : https://ibb.co/5FNTVBf

But I am Getting This : https://ibb.co/MsTqSy4

Comment: when you want to show disable button

Comment: if the conditions meet for the database values and I have to disable the Button for 7776000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `disabled` attribute to button if condition match

```
 @php($found = false)
 @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
       @if($doctor->transaction_id != NULL && $doctor->plan == "90" && $doctor->cabin == "Cabin 1" && $doctor->day =="Friday" && $doctor->time == "8.00 - 10.00") 
           @php($found = true) 
       @endif
@endforeach



    @if($found)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg matchButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" disabled>8.00 - 10.00</button>&nbsp;
     @else
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">8.00 - 10.00</button>&nbsp;
    @endif
```

then to enable it after 7776000 milliseconds ,

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.matchButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 7776000);

   });
</script>
```

Comment: but I want to print only a single button

Comment: I dont want it.. Is there any other thing we can do?

Comment: I want to go through the database all over and If there is the condition meeting so I have to disable the Button, Else the Button will be Enabled.. I want only a single button to be disabled or enabled, But it is not Happening

Comment: Yes but We dont have to print the Extra button

Comment: So what to do if the button should have to be enabled

Comment: What I have to do is exactly is to disable for 7776000 the time slot by checking all over database. otherwise enable the button. I want only one button but I am getting many buttons

Comment: please add some screenshots , in your question so it will be better to understand your problem

Comment: https://ibb.co/MsTqSy4  this is output but I want Like this   https://ibb.co/5FNTVBf  and the Button 8.00 to 10.00 is disabled

Comment: But If the Condition doesnt meet the Button will be not be Shown , I don't want that

Comment: So, What to do?? Any Idea??? Either I want t enable or Disable a button